# Problems with Adobe Flash

Tags: lubuntu, flash

I just got Linux Lubuntu 14.04 on my computer and i have some problems with adobe flash. If i do not have my flash installed than youtube videos are working but not all. But when i install flash none of the players are working, not even youtube. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Use Google Chrome from http://google.com/chrome. It is the easiest way to have latest flash.